# Python - Compare two list and returns values more than zero that exist in both list

Tags: python, list

I have two lists:

```
a= [4,5,4,0,1,0]
b= [0,4,4,0,0,0]
```

How can I generate their sub-lists that have values more than zeroes based on indexes in both lists. For example,

```
sub_list_a =[5,4]
sub_list_b = [4,4]
```

The following code produces the sublists. I wonder if there is an elegant way to do this..

```
idxa = [i for i, e in enumerate(a) if e != 0]
idxb = [i for i, e in enumerate(b) if e != 0]

inter = list(set(idxa) & set(idxb))
from operator import itemgetter 
print ('sub_list_a',itemgetter(*inter)(a))
print ('sub_list_a',itemgetter(*inter)(b))
```

Comment: Unclear. Why is `sub_list_b` `[4,5]`? Where does the `5` come from?

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking, can you be more specific?

Comment: Surely the first list should have a 1 in it and a second 4? What have you tried?

Comment: @tobias_k is it clear to you why 1 is not included in `sub_list_a`?

Comment: @shash678 I'd say because there's a `0` at the corresponding index in `b`. My guess is that `sublist_b` should be `[4,4]`, then it kindof makes sense.

Comment: That makes sense :)

Comment: yes, sublist_b should be [4,4]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#zip) the two lists and check whether both elements are `> 0`, then `zip` again to distribute the pairs to the two sub-lists

```
>>> a= [4, 5, 4, 0, 1, 0]
>>> b= [0, 4, 4, 0, 0, 0]
>>> pairs = [(x, y) for (x, y) in zip(a, b) if x > 0 and y > 0]
>>> sub_list_a, sub_list_b = zip(*pairs)
>>> sub_list_a, sub_list_b
((5, 4), (4, 4))
```

If numbers can not be `< 0`, then you can also just [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#filter) by [`all`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#all):

```
>>> pairs = filter(all, zip(a, b))
>>> sub_list_a, sub_list_b = zip(*pairs)
>>> sub_list_a, sub_list_b
((5, 4), (4, 4))
```

Note that the sublists are tuples; if you need lists, [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#map) to `list`:

```
>>> sub_list_a, sub_list_b = map(list, zip(*pairs))
>>> sub_list_a, sub_list_b
([5, 4], [4, 4])
```

Of course, you can also do all of the above in a single line:

```
sub_list_a, sub_list_b = map(list, zip(*filter(all, zip(a, b))))
```

Answer (score 0):

With list comprehension:

```
>>> sub_a = [a[i] for i in range(0, len(a)) if a[i] > 0 and b[i] > 0]

>>> sub_b = [b[i] for i in range(0, len(b)) if a[i] > 0 and b[i] > 0]

>>> sub_a
[5, 4]

>>> sub_b
[4, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are more comfortable with for loops assuming the lists are the same length:

```
a = [4,5,4,0,1,0]
b = [0,4,4,0,0,0]

def sub_list(l_1, l_2):
  sublist = []
  for idx, val in enumerate(l_1):
    if val > 0 and l_2[idx] !=0:
      sublist.append(val)
  return sublist

print(sub_list(a,b)) #[5, 4]
print(sub_list(b,a)) #[4, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy

a= [4,5,4,0,1,0]
b= [0,4,4,0,0,0]
# get all nonzeros index
sub_a = numpy.nonzero(a)[0]  # [0 1 2 4]
sub_b = numpy.nonzero(b)[0]  # [1,2]
# find intersection
intersect = numpy.intersect1d(sub_a, sub_b) # [1,2]
# a and b index, based on intersection
result = [[a[o], b[o]] for o in intersect]
print (result)

[[5, 4], [4, 4]]
```